# What's an "umbrella" word for attendees and invitees?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm hosting an event. Some people have confirmed their attendance, the attendees. Others have been invited but not responded, invitees.

What is a single word to refer to both groups of people?

Comment: Attendees are those who attend, not those who say they're going to.

Comment: _Colleagues_ is a nice friendly democratic word. Providing you're at the conference, too.

Comment: Why do you need an umbrella term? Is it an outdoor event?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have invited *guests*. Some have responded. Some have not.

Comment: Umm, if I haven't replied to your invitation, I'm not your guest...

Comment: @einpoklum You don't have to use the word umm. You only have to be invited.

Answer (score 3):

*Guests*/audience: Confirmed and Unconfirmed.

Answer (score 1):

An *invitee* is an invited person. Some of those have responded and confirmed their attendance or absence. Those who actually participate are the attendees. The rest are just invitees who haven't responded.

See [invitee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invitee) and [attendee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attendee).

Comment: Not all attendees were invited. Some have become attendees by their own choice, registration was open.

Comment: @MattPotts: True, but an open invitation is still an invitation. It has some target audience, no matter how large, which are the invitees.

Comment: @MattPotts: Well, if I wasn't invited, am I not a crashee rather than an attendee? :-)

Comment: Uninvited attendee.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need a single word for both? Language doesn't necessarily come pre-packaged. The 'attendees' are the ones who do come, not the ones who just say they are coming.

'Those who are invited' and 'those who attend'.

Comment: DO NOT comment on my comments.